# Permission problem on Mojave and High Sierra

Tags: finder, permission

I received an error saying "The folder  can't be opened because you don't have permission to see it's content." This is on an external drive and it's only happening to one specific folder on that drive. I checked the permissions and it says the top line says "I can only read", yet under the table, it lists my name and shows that I can read and write.

The only thing that I can think of doing differently was renaming the drive so not sure if that caused it. But then, why am I able to view the other folders in the same drive?

[image: Sharing and Permissions]

Comment: Can you open Terminal, run `ls -0leO@d` on the folder and add the result to the question?

Comment: This is the response:  is a directory

Comment: Is this the only response? Please copy/paste both the command you ran and all the output you got to the question

Comment: Sorry about that. Here you go:

Comment: Last login: Fri Aug  9 13:15:38 on ttys000
lt-053:~ ericlee$ /Volumes/Portable\ 2TB/chasing\ the\ Sun\ Vlogs/Taiwan\ Trip\ 2019 ls -0leO@d
-bash: /Volumes/Portable 2TB/chasing the Sun Vlogs/Taiwan Trip 2019: is a directory
lt-053:~ ericlee$

Comment: Try clicking on the lock, unlock it, click your name, change Read & Write to Read Only, click again, change back to Read & Right. Also check the permission on the parent folder, because it can be causing effects too on it.